# How to handle unsigned shorts/ints/longs in Java

Tags: java, groovy

I'm reading a file format that specifies some types are unsigned integers and shorts. When I read the values, I get them as a byte array. The best route to turning them into shorts/ints/longs I've seen is something like this:

```
ByteBuffer wrapped = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray);
int x = wrapped.getInt();
```

That looks like it could easily overflow for unsigned ints. Is there a better way to handle this scenario?

**Update**: I should mention that I'm using Groovy, so I absolutely don't care if I have to use a `BigInteger` or something like that. I just want the maximum safety on keeping the value intact.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with them.  If you want to use them as actual numeric values you'll have to read them, promote (i.e. assign) them to the next larger size and then mask off the possibly extended sign bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A 32bit value, signed or unsigned, can always be stored losslessly in an `int`*. This means that you never have to worry about putting unsigned values in signed types from a data safety point of view.

The same is true for 8bit values in `byte`s, 16bit values in `short`s and 64bit values in `long`s.

Once you've read an unsigned value into the corresponding signed type, you can promote them to signed values of a larger types to more easily work with the intended value:

- [Integer.toUnsignedLong(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toUnsignedLong-int-)
- [Short.toUnsignedInt(short)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Short.html#toUnsignedInt-short-)
- [Byte.toUnsignedInt(byte)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#toUnsignedInt-byte-)

Since there's no primitive type larger than `long`, you can either go via BigInteger, or use the convenience methods on `Long` to do unsigned operations:

- BigInteger.valueOf([Long.toUnsignedString(long)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toUnsignedString-long-))
- [Long.divideUnsigned(long,long)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#divideUnsigned-long-long-) and friends

---

* This is thanks to the JVM requiring [integer types to be two's complement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.3).

Comment: Nice, I didn't know these were added in Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

To hold an unsigned int/short/byte, you need to use the next "bigger" type, i.e. long/int/short. If you already hold the value in the signed type that can overflow, the conversion can be done by doing the following:

```
int unsignedVal = byteVal & 0xff
```

If you just cast them, the negative-bit will be regarded and you will still end up with the negative value.

If you have to handle unsigned longs you need to "switch" to java.math.BigInteger.

Answer (score 1):

Unsigned primitives are a pain in Java.

There's no clean way of handing them, except using larger types with more bits, and taking care to avoid automatic sign extension when casting.

In your case, you can do something like this:

```
ByteBuffer wrapped = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray);
int signedInt = wrapped.getInt();
long unsigned = signedInt & 0xffffffffL;
```

I usually write the required conversion(s) in a utility class someplace, since they're easy to get wrong. If you copy & paste that one liner conversion everywhere, eventually one will be wrong.

Note that if you need unsigned longs, the only larger type is `BigInteger`.

If you need anything more than simple conversions, I suggest using Guava since it has some nice classes for dealing with unsigned types. See documentation [here](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PrimitivesExplained#unsigned-support).